# How to keep track of high score in java?

Tags: java

The purpose of the Java program is to pick a random integer between 0 and 11 inclusive every time you press a button. If the integer is 1 or 2 then the total is 0. otherwise the integer is added to the running total. I've done all that but I can't figure out how to update the high score (it's supposed to update whenever a higher score is achieved).

```
public void update() { 
  int value = ((int)(Math.random() * (11 - 1 + 1) + 1)); 
  label1.setText("Value: " + value); 

  if (value < 3) { 
    total = 0; 
  } else {
    total = value + total;
  }

  label2.setText("Total: " + total); 

  if (highScore <= total) { 
    label3.setText("High Score: " + highScore); 
  }
}
```

But I know the last part won't work because I haven't done anything with the variable highScore.

Comment: Can't you just add `highScore = total` inside your `if`?

Comment: "I haven't done anything with the variable highScore" so do something with like, like you have does with `total` for example.  It's not clear what is stopping you.

Comment: initially set high score to zero, and then before exiting make total as the new high score if it is greater than the high score.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(highScore < total) 
 { 
  highScore = total;
  label3.setText("High Score: " + highScore); 
 }
```

Note, I think you want < rather than <=

Answer (score 2):

You must initialise `highScore = 0` while declaring. Then after getting a highScore you should update the value of highScore with new value.

Try this,

```
public void update() {

    int value = ((int) (Math.random() * 11 + 1));
    label1.setText("Value: " + value);

    if (value < 3) {
        total = 0;
    } else
        total = value + total;

    label2.setText("Total: " + total);

    if (highScore < total) {
        highScore = total;
        label3.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `highScore = 0;` whereever you first declare it.

Then add this line to the if statement

```
if (highScore <= total) {
    label3.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
    highScore = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare `highScore` OUTSIDE of the update method. `highScore` will be thrown away when you exit the method and created again when you enter the update method, so it'll always be what you initially initialize it to. You have to initialize `highScore` to a minimum value that you won't encounter in your program. Your best bet is to use `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

```
int highScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public void update()
{
    ...
}
```

Next, you need to test if the total is higher than `highScore`. If the total is higher, then update `highScore` to the total. NOTE: using < or <= is up to you, it won't change the `highScore`. It depends on if you are determining who last reached the high score (which it doesn't look like you are doing), so using < won't perform unneeded operations.

```
if (highScore < total) {
    label3.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
    highScore = total;
}
```